# Formatting entires of ToC according to chapter/sections using titletoc/titlesec

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, titletoc

In my book, I need my chapters to be bold-face and uppercase, my sections to be uppercase and regular, subsections to be bold and regular case and subsubsections to be italic regular case.

In the text, I managed to accomplish that using the titletoc/titlesec package. However, in the `\tableofcontents`, the entries only format accordingly with bold and italics. I can't make the chapter/section names uppercase at all! Everything else is just the way I need it to be.

I added the `\MakeUppercase` to several places in the `\titlecontents` but I'd either produce an error or it wouldn't work at all.

Can someone shed some light on what im f*cking up here?

Here's my MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{temp.bib}
@book{sadiku,
    author = {Alexander, C.K. and Sadiku, M.N.O.},
    title = {Fundamentos de Circuitos Elétricos},
    edition = {5ª edição},
    isbn = {978-85-8055-173-0},
    publisher = {{AMGH} Editora},
    location = {Porto Alegre},
    date = {2013}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents                {chapter}[3.5pc]{\bfseries}{\contentslabel{3.5pc}}{}{\titlerule*[0.3pc]{.}\contentspage}
\titlecontents                {section}[3.5pc]{}         {\contentslabel{3.5pc}}{}{\titlerule*[0.3pc]{.}\contentspage}
\titlecontents             {subsection}[3.5pc]{\bfseries}{\contentslabel{3.5pc}}{}{\titlerule*[0.3pc]{.}\contentspage}
\titlecontents          {subsubsection}[3.5pc]{\itshape} {\contentslabel{3.5pc}}{}{\titlerule*[0.3pc]{.}\contentspage}
\titlecontents{numberless-entry-format}[3.5pc]{}         {\contentslabel{3.5pc}}{}{\titlerule*[0.3pc]{.}\contentspage}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\let\cleardoublepage=\clearpage

\addto\captionsportuguese{\renewcommand\contentsname{\hfill\bfseries\MakeUppercase Sumário \hfill}}
\addto\captionsportuguese{\renewcommand\listfigurename{\hfill\bfseries\MakeUppercase Lista de Figuras \hfill}}
\addto\captionsportuguese{\renewcommand\listtablename{\hfill\bfseries\MakeUppercase Lista de Tabelas \hfill}}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat      {\chapter}[hang]{\bfseries\MakeUppercase}{\thechapter}      {10pt}{\bfseries}
\titleformat      {\section}[hang]{\MakeUppercase}         {\thesection}      {10pt}{}
\titleformat   {\subsection}[hang]{\bfseries}              {\thesubsection}   {10pt}{\bfseries}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[hang]{\itshape}               {\thesubsubsection}{10pt}{\itshape}

\titlespacing      {\chapter}{0pt}{-20pt}{5pt}
\titlespacing      {\section}{0pt}{5pt}  {5pt}
\titlespacing   {\subsection}{0pt}{5pt}  {5pt}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0pt}{5pt}  {5pt}

\usepackage[style=abnt, extrayear, url=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{temp.bib}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
\cite{sadiku}

{\linespread{1} 
\printbibliography[
    heading=bibintoc,   % Faz aparecer a bibliografia no sumário
    title={Referências Bibliográficas} % Muda o nome do capítulo
    ]}

\chapter*{Numberless chapter}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Numberless chapter}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to answer my original question AND find the original error that the MWE didn't contemplate.

The `\MakeUppercase` has to be added after the `\contentslabel{3.5pc}`. I'll only post the excerpt with all the `\titlecontents{...}`:

```
\titlecontents                {chapter}[3.5pc]{\bfseries}{\contentslabel{3.5pc}\MakeUppercase}{\MakeUppercase}{\titlerule*[0.3pc]{.}\contentspage}
\titlecontents                {section}[3.5pc]{}         {\contentslabel{3.5pc}\MakeUppercase}{}{\titlerule*[0.3pc]{.}\contentspage}
\titlecontents             {subsection}[3.5pc]{\bfseries}{\contentslabel{3.5pc}}{}{\titlerule*[0.3pc]{.}\contentspage}
\titlecontents          {subsubsection}[3.5pc]{\itshape} {\contentslabel{3.5pc}}{}{\titlerule*[0.3pc]{.}\contentspage}
\titlecontents{numberless-entry-format}[3.5pc]{}         {\contentslabel{3.5pc}}{}{\titlerule*[0.3pc]{.}\contentspage}
```

Still not sure if the last one does anything useful.

Now I found out that there are conflicts between titletoc and hiperref. <s>I'll go on to research on that! But the original question regarding the MWE was answered! I just didn't created a proper MWE to begin with...</s>

I managed to find [this post](https://groups.google.com/g/comp.text.tex/c/rXbFGDych8o) that answers my question.
Since I use `\chapter*{}` for appendix, the author's problem didn't happen in my code.
To sum up, the problem happens because of the `\MakeUppercase` command. Replacing it with the `\uppercase` command works ok for me.
Dunno wheter this is good practice or not. Maybe there are better ways using other packages. But I guess, since it works, it's ok?

Final excerpt:

```
\titlecontents                {chapter}[3.5pc]{\bfseries}{\contentslabel{3.5pc}\uppercase}{\uppercase}{\titlerule*[0.3pc]{.}\contentspage}
\titlecontents                {section}[3.5pc]{}         {\contentslabel{3.5pc}\uppercase}{}{\titlerule*[0.3pc]{.}\contentspage}
\titlecontents             {subsection}[3.5pc]{\bfseries}{\contentslabel{3.5pc}}{}{\titlerule*[0.3pc]{.}\contentspage}
\titlecontents          {subsubsection}[3.5pc]{\itshape} {\contentslabel{3.5pc}}{}{\titlerule*[0.3pc]{.}\contentspage}
\titlecontents{numberless-entry-format}[3.5pc]{}         {\contentslabel{3.5pc}}{}{\titlerule*[0.3pc]{.}\contentspage}
```